# Create a function to change bin size in a histogram with hist in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, histogram

Write a function that accepts a vector, a vector of integers, a main axis label and an x axis label. This function should iterate over each element in the vector of integers and produce a histogram for each integer value, setting the bin count to the element in the input vector, and labeling main and x-axis with the specified parameters. You should label the y-axis to read Frequency, bins = and the number of bins.

I am trying this but it is not reading in the nclass for the three different bin sizes correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

```
plot.historgrams <- function(x,nclass, ...){
  for (i in 1:length(nclass)) {
  hist(x,nclass=nclass[i], ...)
  }
}

plot.histograms(hidalgo.dat[,1], c(12,36,60), main="1872 Hidalgo 
   issue",xlab= "Thickness (mm)")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working when I use breaks and put an x= in front of the data set.

```
plot.historgrams <- function(x,b, ...){
  for (i in 1:length(b)){
  hist(x=x,breaks=b[i], ylab=paste("Frequency, bins= ",b[i]),  ...)
  }
}

plot.historgrams(x=hidalgo.dat[,1], c(12,36,60), main="1872 Hidalgo issue",xlab= "Thickness (mm)")
```

Comment: Does anyone know why I have to put x = in there?